# Excel VBA "Like" not Selecting for "*M*"

Tags: excel, vba

The following code executes the "Then" statement for a folder with the name of "2017-10-16" without an "M", even though the code seems to require that it both have an "M" and a date as well.  Does anyone know why the first part of the statement is returning true for a folder without an "M", or what else may be going on here?

```
    If _
        objSubFolder.Path Like "*M*" And _
        objSubFolder.Path Like "*" & Format(DateLoop, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "*" _
    Then
        MsgBox objSubFolder.Name
```

Comment: Could you provide the string of a Path example that doesn't contain M and still return True?

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for turning the light on.  I know what you're getting at, I'm debugging for the path name and it definitely does have an M in it.  I first need to parse the folder name from the path and then test for the M.

Comment: If you post something akin to that as an answer I will vote for it as an answer.

Comment: You are welcome, there is no need for an answer, since a simple comment alerted you. You can post an answer of your code correction with the parsed name path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the .Path method instead of the .Name method, so I was pulling the entire path instead of the folder name.

```
If _
    objSubFolder.Name Like "*M*" And _
    objSubFolder.Name Like "*" & Format(DateLoop, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "*" _
Then
    MsgBox objSubFolder.Name
```

Works.